# Retrieve accounts-github accesstoken

Tags: meteor, github-api

I'm writing a third party package that uses the GitHub API. I'm now trying to use the `accessToken` from the `accounts-github` package in order to make authenticated GitHub API requests.

How can I retrieve the `accessToken` from `accounts-github`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it from the server side its as follows:

```
var user = Meteor.user().services.github.accessToken;
```

On the client side its a bit tricky because the `services` field is not published. You can publish it if you run a publish method as follows:

```
Meteor.publish('account', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{fields:{services: 1}});
});
```

I would recommend storing the `accessToken` in profile when you create the user alongwith anything else you need on the client.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if (options.profile)
        user.profile = options.profile;
    user.profile.github_accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken;
    return user;
});
```

You can then access the `accessToken` on either the client or the server with `Meteor.user().profile.github_accessToken`